# Azure Traffic Manager connects to the Private Endpoints (Internal ingress)

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I am looking for a AKS Disaster recovery(DR) solution, I was trying with Traffic manager but it seems it only supporting for Web App public endpoints, is there a solution coming near future for connecting internal web app endpoints(private). In my environment all backend system mostly running on internal network. So i need to implement a solution for connecting those private web app endpoints.
Please let me know if there is a solution already if not any new feature is coming for Traffic Manager in future.

Answer (score 3):

Traffic Manager works at DNS level, it can route traffic that originates from the public internet to a set of endpoints that are also internet-facing and you cannot use Traffic Manager to route endpoints inside a private endpoint. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#what-types-of-traffic-can-be-routed-using-traffic-manager).

Also, you can vote up [this request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/37204342-traffic-manager-private-endpoints) for the supported private endpoint and as a workaround, you may use a Function App to monitor a private endpoint, and reprogram your ATM profile to enable only endpoints that are currently available. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/mihansen/using-azure-traffic-manager-for-private-endpoint-failover-automation).

From the above Azure team feedback, it seems there is no plan for such a supporting private endpoint feature as the traffic manager is essentially global and public.

Comment: Updated feedback request link - https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aa123491-8a26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789